# How could I run unit tests in Supervisor context?

Tags: python, unit-testing, supervisord

I am building a complex Python application that distributes data between very different services, devices, and APIs. Obviously, there is a lot of private authentication information. I am handling it by passing it with environmental variables within a Supervisor process using the `environment=` keyword in the configuration file.

I have also a test that checks whether all API authentication information is set up correctly and whether the external APIs are available. Currently I am using Nosetest as test runner.

Is there a way to run the tests in the Supervisor context without brute force parsing the supervisor configuration file within my test runner?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use Python Celery which is already installed on my machine. My API queries are wrapped as tasks and send to Celery. Given this setup I created my testrunner as just another task that runs the API tests.

The web application tests do not need the stored credentials but run fine in the Celery context as well.